# ¿como paso archivos con cmd en Sockets Java TCP?

Tags: java, socket, tcp

como server uso netcat,

mi cliente es este, pero no puedo lograr pasar archivos.
quiero tener acceso al cmd del cliente

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  

public class MyClient {  

public static void main(String[] args) {  
 try{      
    Socket s=new Socket("localhost",6666);  
    DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
    dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");  
    dout.flush();  
    dout.close();  
    s.close();  
  }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
  }  
 }  
}
```

Comment: Y por que dices que no funciona? Llega al catch? Si es así, qué se imprime en ese `println(e)`? Y si pruebas `println( e.getMessage() )`?

Comment: No dije que no funciona, funciona bien , llega el mensaje todo, pero lo que yo quiero es tener acceso al cmd del cliente y es eso lo que no puedo lograr.

Comment: Te sugiero que expliques mejor que problemas estás teniendo y a qué te refieres con "tener acceso al cmd del cliente".

Comment: cuando ejecute el cliente en otra PC (ordenador) quiero tener acceso desde mi PC a su CMD (Consola) para poder pasar archivos, imagenes, etc...